# How to load compressed chekpoint file with Torch to Tacotron2 model

Tags: zip, gzip, torch, rar

I'm tring to apply MBP(Magnitude Based Pruning) algorithm On Tacotron2. i did it successfuly,i got Many chekpoints based on K% sparsity on gzip format .

After that i tried runing the model inference by loading those new chekpoints with gzip format to my model (it use Pytorch)

The problem that is :

```
tacotron2 = torch.load("path.tar.gz") #dont work .
```

So please any idea about how loading gzip chekpoint to torch .

Answer (score 0):

I did Find the solution by :

```
import pickle

import tarfile

from torch.serialization import _load, _open_zipfile_reader

#Function to load file
def torch_load_targz(filep_ath):
  tar = tarfile.open(filep_ath, "r:gz")
  member = tar.getmembers()[0]
  with tar.extractfile(member) as untar:
    with _open_zipfile_reader(untar) as zipfile:
        torch_loaded = _load(zipfile, None, pickle)
  return torch_loaded

# Try the function
tacotron2 = torch_load_targz('path.tar.gz')
tacotron2.eval()
```